# How to manipulate Claims in ASP.NET Core 5 with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I am investigating using Windows Authentication with ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC. I can use an Active Directory group name directly in the `Authorize` attribute, but that's proved problematic in the past.

I want to add claims to the list and use those values in the `Authorize` attributes. Various posts suggested that if I implemented an `IClaimsTransformation`, `TransformAsync()` would be called automatically but that doesn't appear to be the case. I never see the string `In TransformAsync` in the output in Visual Studio.

I am using VS 2019 and ASP.NET Core 5.0.

To recreate: I use a new ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) template:

- Target Framework: .NET 5.0 (Current)
- Authentication Type: Windows,
- Configure for HTTPS: yes

When I run it, I can see that I'm authenticated from the Hello `DOMAIN\User` message.

These are my additions:

`ADClaimsTransformation.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOWinAuthN1.Services
{
    public class ADClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("In TransformAsync");
            var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
            var c = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, "Admin");
            ci.AddClaim(c);

            return Task.FromResult(principal);
        }
    }
}
```

I can see from the Output window that this is never called.

In `Startup.cs`, I have:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SOWinAuthN1.Services;

namespace SOWinAuthN1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ADClaimsTransformation>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`SecureController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SOWinAuthN1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class SecureController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(HttpContext.User.Claims);
        }
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` (located in `.\Views\Secure`):

```
@model IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Claims";
}

<h1>Claims</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Issuer</th>
            <th>OriginalIssuer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Subject</td>
            <td>@item.Type</td>
            <td>@item.Value</td>
            <td>@item.Issuer</td>
            <td>@item.OriginalIssuer</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`_Layout.cshtml` - added to the navbar `ul`:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Secure" asp-action="Index">Claims</a>
</li>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Is there a better approach?

Ultimately, I'm expecting to have a transformer which maps a small number of AD group claims onto a larger number of operations, such that group A maps to operations 1, 2 and 4, whilst group B maps to 2, 4 and 5, say, with the plan to keep this mapping in config somewhere.

Comment: how did you set up auth services & middleware? include those in the post, too

Comment: I've included the whole of Startup.cs - does that supply what you asked for?  Core is new to me so I'm still finding my feet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing `services.AddAuthentication()` in your `ConfigureServices` method and `app.UseAuthentication()` in your `Configure` method.

You can have a look at [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth) for more information on how to configure Kestrel or IIS or HTTP.sys.

Comment: Authentication works without them, as in `<p class="nav navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>` from `_Layout.cshtml` is rendered correctly as `Hello, MYDOMAIN\MyUserId!` and if I comment out the `[Authorize]` attribute, the Secure page displays my AD group membership.

Comment: I tried adding both statements but it made no difference.

Comment: @user2871239 this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the previous instructions but
it's important you add `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization()`